# How to match a group of lines that match a pattern

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to filter out a group of lines that match a pattern using a regexp but am having trouble getting the correct regexp to use.

The text file contains lines like this:

```
transaction 390134; promote; 2016/12/20 01:17:07 ; user: build
  to: DEVELOPMENT ; from: DEVELOPMENT_BUILD
  #  some commit comment
  /./som/file/path 11745/409 (22269/257) 

  # merged
  version 22269/257 (22269/257)
  ancestor: (22133/182)

transaction 390136; promote; 2016/12/20 01:17:08 ; user: najmi
  to: DEVELOPMENT ; from: DEVELOPMENT_BUILD
  /./some/other/file/path 11745/1 (22269/1) 

  version 22269/1 (22269/1)
  ancestor: (none - initial version)
  type: dir
```

I would like to filter out the lines that start with "transaction", contain "User: build all the way until the next line that starts with "transaction".

The idea is to end up with transaction lines where user is not "build".

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want this? https://regex101.com/r/DOeWXt/1

Comment: @ Mr. Kang Thanks for showing the cool regex101.com site. The regexp as shown does not match the entire transaction record spanning several lines so this is not exactly what I was looking for. I would be grateful for a pure regexp solution that is equivalent to the perl solution kindly given by pii_ke.

Comment: @Mr.kang I got following regexp to work in the link you gave:

^transaction.+?user:\s(?!build)(.|\n)+

However, I am having trouble getting that to work with following grep command:

grep "^transaction.+?user:\s(?!build)(.|\n)+" test_data.txt

Comment: `grep -P "^transaction.+?user:\s(?"'!'"build)(.|\n)+" test.log`   refer to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33339/cant-use-exclamation-mark-in-bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only the transaction lines for all users except `build`:

```
grep '^transaction ' test_data| grep -v 'user: build$'
```

If you want the whole transaction record for such users:

```
awk '/^transaction /{ p = !/user: build$/};p' test_data
```

OR

```
perl -lne 'if(/^transaction /){$p = !/user: build$/}; print if $p' test_data
```

The `-A` and `-v` options of `grep` command would have done the trick if all transaction records had same number of lines.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. If any one has a pure grep solution please share as perl is not currently installed for us.

Comment: @FarrukhNajmi i've added another command that does the same thing, might prove useful if you have `awk` installed.